# Methods for side-effects in purely functional programming languages

Tags: monads, continuations, side-effects, purely-functional, effect-systems

At the moment I'm aware of the following methods to integrate side-effects into purely functional programming languages:

- effect systems
- continuations
- unique types
- monads

Monads are often cited to be the most effective and most general way to do this.

Which other methods exist? How do they compare?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666618/possible-means-of-side-effectst-in-purely-functional-languages ?

Answer (score 1):

[Arrows](http://www.haskell.org/arrows/), which are more general than monads.

Answer (score 0):

The very simplest method is to simply pass around the environment between the functions.  This is often used to teach scheme.

Answer (score 0):

To me a more general way is via a monad/comonad pair.  This generalizes the common "monad" approach which should correctly be called the "strong monad" approach, since it only works with strong monads.

Moving to a monad/comonad pair allows effects to be modeled that result in some variables no longer being available.  An example where this is useful is the effect of migrating a thread to another host in a distributed setting.

An additional method of historical interest is to make the whole program a function mapping a stream/list of input events to a stream/list of output events.  See: "How to Declare an Imperative" by Phil Wadler: http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/~wadler/topics/monads.html#monadsdeclare